# How to integrate a custom HTML file in a Rails file

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I made a front-end for my login page. Now I want the back-end (login, signup, ...). I saw a tutorial on YouTube from the gem named 'Devise'. Looks pretty awesome.

So I've these standard devise 'registrations/new.html.erb' file.

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password %>
  <% if @minimum_password_length %>
   <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
  <% end %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
</div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

This is my custom file, it use Bootstrap. 'sign_up.html.erb'

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="box">
 <h2 class="title">Sign Up</h2>
  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="first_name">First name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="last_name">Last name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email address:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    <%= link_to 'Cancel', sign_login_path, class: 'btn btn-default' %>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

So my question is, how can I add these two files to one file. Keep the layout from my custom file but use the back-end code from the devine file.

Comment: The gem you saw is Devise (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).

Comment: yeah, sorry :-/ I edit it ;-)

Comment: Never mind. It happens sometimes.

Comment: There's a few Devise+Bootstrap plugins you might want to try before going down this road.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parts between `<%= %>` are ruby code, use the ruby code from devise in your page, keeping your layout. `<%= form_for %>` will output the `<form>` element configured for devise, `<%= f.label %>` are `<label>`, `<%= f.something_field %>` are `<input>` and `<%= f.submit %>` is the `<button>`.

You can pass class and id as follow :

```
<%= f.email_field :name, autofocus: true, class: "form-control", id: "email" %>
```

Hard to say more without doing it for you.